# How to solve for the actual value of a relative error function?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, absolute-value

Given the following equation, how do I solve for both values of α
?
$$\Delta=\frac{\lvert\alpha-\beta\rvert}{\alpha}$$
For context, in Numerical Analysis $\beta$ represents an estimate, to an actual value, $\alpha$, and $\Delta$ represents their difference.

I have tried to experiment with inequality properties of the absolute value function, but that might give me a range of values, instead of two values of $\alpha$. Additionally, I couldn't find any helpful absolute value properties online.

Bonus points for recommending good reads/cheat-sheets on absolute value properties with example problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $\alpha$, such that
$$|\alpha-\beta|=\alpha \Delta$$

Now, since $|x|=y \implies x=\pm y$, we get
$$\begin{align}
\alpha-\beta =\pm \alpha \Delta &\implies \alpha\mp \alpha\Delta = \beta \\
&\implies \alpha(1\mp \Delta)=\beta \\
&\implies \alpha_{1,2}=\frac{\beta}{1\pm \Delta}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: No reason for the change from -+ to +- in the final implication, right?

Comment: Correct (one solution is given by the $+$ and the other by the $-$, the order doesn't matter here).